# Rails: share params between controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3 app and I'm developing a bot over it.

The basic idea is that an user will be able to communicate with the app using its favourite messaging service. The bot will then evaluate the received message and direct the message to the proper controller and action. Please keep in mind that this shouldn't be done in the routing level since the evaluation requires to execute queries, some logic etc.

Although I know is possible to send params to another Controller and action simply by passing variable to the respective methods ( refactoring the method with default values for the variables --something like `def hello( var_a = params['one'] , var_b = params['tow']...`) I wouldn't like to go this way since it would require to refactor a lot of written code.

In this context, I was thinking it its possible to create an initialize method in the controller I will need to pass the params. Something like:

```
ExistingController < ApplicationController

def self.start_with_external_params ( params )
    # some code here 
end
```

And then use the passed params as usually in the controller -- by calling `ExistingController.new.start_with_external_params(params).some_method` but I couldn't figure out how to make it, can someone give me some advice on this matter?

Comment: Inheritance is not working in this case or what?

Comment: why do you inherit your controller from AR::Base?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Sorry, that was a typo, indeed it's inherit from the  `ApplicationController` - I just corrected it.

Comment: @radubogdan Inheritance works. I know that the usual way of doing it is by using `redirect_to` or `render` but I can't do it. with `render ..` I get a `ActionView::MissingTemplate`error or a `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` if I try to include a `render :nothing => true`  (indeed, the template is in the existing controller) while the `redirect_to` cannot be used because I'm dealing with an external server, and it will not follow the redirection.

Comment: (Just completing the context)  I can't call  `ExistingController.new.existing_method`  because I get `NoMethodError (undefined method `parameters' for nil:NilClass): ` since the params are not passed to the existing controller...

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful. In short, I think you may want to check out redirecting.

Your stated scenario sorta mentions you're in one controller, action and wanting to get to another.

Hope this helps: [Render and Redirect in Rails 3](https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1210155)

Comment: Hi, 
I can't use `render 'ExistingController/ExistingMethod' ` because I get a ` ActionView::MissingTemplate ` error (the render is done in the ExistingController) while, if I add, before the `render 'ExistingController/ExistingMethod' `   a `render :nothing => true` I get an `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`  .
Also, I can't use a redirect_to because I'm dealing with an API, and the foreign server will not follow the redirection.

Comment: Seeing your code might help. Are you redirecting from one server to another? Or are you staying local once the foreign server calls you and are still getting an error?

Comment: Hi @gabriel , I'm not redirecting from one server to another: I'm staying local once the foreign server calls me. That said, I can't ask the foreign server to follow the redirection. Therefore, a think a `render` **could be** more appropriate, but can't get it work without errors since the template is on the existing controller..